# What is the order of returned document?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection and I do this query :

```
db.getCollection("test").find(
{"$or":[{_id:NumberLong("1234")},
        {_id:NumberLong("1230")},
        {_id:NumberLong("1237")},
        {_id:NumberLong("1236")}}
)
```

**In with order will be the returned documents** ? I need this exact order (with is the order of the `$or` statement) :

```
1234
1230
1237
1236
```

normally it's the order I see when I do the previous query, but today I saw one query that return me a different order (and this just one time, because after i restarted the server the order was good again). So what to do to have exactly the exact order I need ?

Comment: It's not guaranteed unless you're explicit about it; it'll be whatever order they were found in unless told otherwise. You can read about ordering options in the docs for your library.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/index.html) to make sure that results are returned in the order you want. Since there's no natural candidate for "sort" field in your model you can use [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html) and add temporary field just for `$sort` purpose. It can be evaluated using [$indexOfArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/index.html) operator. You can use that field for filtering purpose as well (`$indexOfArray` returns `-1` if there's no match

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            order: { $indexOfArray: [ [NumberLong("1234"), NumberLong("1230"), NumberLong("1237"), NumberLong("1236") ], "$_id" ] }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: { order: { $ne: -1 } }
    },
    {
        $sort: { order:1 }
    },
    {
        $project: { order: 0 }
    }
])
```

Comment: thanks mickl, it's an idea to use addFields !